# What is the IAM role needed for grant the IAM right "dialogflow.agents.restore" on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to use DialogFlow Agent API using HTTP calls but it seem that I didn't have the right to use it. I don't find the right IAM role for using it.

I've tried to give all IAM roles related to DialogFlow to the service account that I use but I always get an HTTP 403 error.
I know that my authentification is correct because I can call others API from DialogFlow.

There is the curl request that I use.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/<AGENT_NAME>/agent:restore \
  -H 'Authorization: <BEARER_TOKEN>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
  "agentContent": "<ZIP_FILE_BASE64>"
}'
```

There is the response given by the API.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "IAM permission 'dialogflow.agents.restore' on 'projects/<AGENT_NAME>' denied.",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 roles which provide **dialogflow.agents.restore**.

[image]

You'll want to make sure the IAM owner of the token in the request has at least one of these roles assigned to it under the appropriate project.